# Refresh ListView grouped items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, refresh, grouping

I have a `ListView`, that implements a `GridView` as `View`, where items are grouped (using `Expander`) according to a field which is rappresented by a `ComboBox`.

The `ItemsSource` of my `ListView` is binded with an `ObservableCollection` of:

```
public class data
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public bool Graduate { get; set; }
   public eMusic Music { get; set; }
}

public enum eMusic
{
    Rock,
    Pop,
    Classic
}
```

Where the value of `Music` property is shown by the `ComboBox`.

[image]

The problem is the following: when I change the value of a ComboBox (for example Pop -> Rock) the relative item is not moved in the corresponding group. Why? How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

[MainWindow.xaml](http://ideone.com/xO8JP)
[MainWindow.xaml.cs](http://ideone.com/rNsia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I edit the `ComboBox` I have to refresh the `ItemsSource` of my `ListView`:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListView.ItemsSource);
view.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`in combobox xaml atrributes

Write a property on your viewmodel like this

```
    private ICollectionView _musicsView;
    public ObservableCollection<Music> Musics{ get; private set; }

    public YourViewModel()
    { 
       Musics= new ObservableCollection<Music>();
       _music= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvaibleLanguages);
       _music.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(OnCurrentChanged);
    }

    public ICollectionView MusicsView
    {
       get
       {
          return _musicsView;
       } 
    }

    void OnCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YourObject current = _musicsView.CurrentItem as YourItem;
//do: what you want
    }
```

Comment: It does not work, with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" when I change a ComboBox (Pop -> Rock) all the ComboBox values become Rock.